# Elasticsearch Disk Space Issues after Close/Open Index

Tags: elasticsearch, diskspace

I recently needed to open & close an Elasticsearch index to add a custom analyzer & create a mapping. Since then, I've been seeing disk space issues across all of nodes and am unsure of the best way to proceed.

Here are some selected lines from the log file on the master node from that day:

```
[2016-03-18 01:54:46,161][INFO ][cluster.metadata] [instance name] closing indices [[prod]]
[2016-03-18 01:54:46,161][INFO ][cluster.metadata] [instance name] opening indices [[prod]]
[2016-03-18 01:54:48,493][WARN ][cluster.routing.allocation.decider] [instance name] After allocating, node [nodename] would have less than the required 0b free bytes threshold (-28916726190 bytes free), preventing allocation
[2016-03-18 01:54:48,494][WARN ][cluster.routing.allocation.decider] [instance name] After allocating, node [nodename] would have less than the required 0b free bytes threshold  (-29217364398 bytes free), preventing allocation
```

... one of these lines for each of the ES nodes ...

Then, what seems like one of these for each node:

```
[2016-03-18 01:54:49,500][DEBUG][action.search.type] [instance name] All shards failed for phase: [query]
org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException: instance name]][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IllegalIndexShardStateException: [prod][0] CurrentState[RECOVERING] operations only allowed when started/relocated
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.readAllowed(IndexShard.java:1000)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.acquireSearcher(IndexShard.java:793)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.acquireSearcher(IndexShard.java:789)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createContext(SearchService.java:552)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createAndPutContext(SearchService.java:532)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:294)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchQueryTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:776)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchQueryTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:767)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler$RequestHandler.doRun(MessageChannelHandler.java:279)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

then, a bunch more of the first blockquoted line, then:

```
[2016-03-18 01:56:39,891][INFO ][cluster.metadata] [instance name] [prod] create_mapping [mapping name]
```

and then two of these lines:

```
[2016-03-18 02:05:18,993][WARN ][cluster.action.shard] [instance name] [prod][1] received shard failed for [prod][1], node[node name], [R], s[INITIALIZING], indexUUID [index id], reason [shard failure [failed recovery][RecoveryFailedException[[prod][1]: Recovery failed from [instance name]{master=true} into [instance name]{master=false}]; nested: RemoteTransportException[[instance name][internal:index/shard/recovery/start_recovery]]; nested: RecoveryEngineException[[prod][1] Phase[1] Execution failed]; nested: RecoverFilesRecoveryException[[prod][1] Failed to transfer [0] files with total size of [0b]]; nested: IllegalStateException[try to recover [prod][1] from primary shard with sync id but number of docs differ: 217250828 (instance name, primary) vs 217250830(instance name)]; ]]
```

and then, a bunch of low-disk and then high-disk watermark errors. These errors have continued happening since the time the open/close commands were run, and as such they are preventing new data from being indexed.

When I run /cat/_shards/prod, I see:

```
index shard prirep state             docs  store ip          node                                    
prod  0     p      STARTED      218452373 73.5gb 
prod  0     r      STARTED      218452373 73.5gb 
prod  0     r      UNASSIGNED                                                                        
prod  1     p      STARTED      217445482 73.1gb 
prod  1     r      STARTED      217445482 73.1gb 
prod  1     r      UNASSIGNED                                                                        
prod  2     r      INITIALIZING                  
prod  2     r      INITIALIZING                 
prod  2     p      STARTED      218665090 73.2gb
```

and note that one of the replica shards for shard 2 oscillates between an INITIALIZING and UNASSIGNED phase.

I am really hoping someone can consult on the best way forward as this problem continues to become more painful each day. The best I can think of now would be to back up all data, update the index settings to have 0 replicas (to get rid of the unassigned shards), and then update to add 1 replica (since I have a feeling that maybe the recovery process inadvertently added a replica). I can't figure out how to confirm this theory, the most I could discern is that we did not override the default setting in elasticsearch.yml (and the default is 1 replica), and our ec2 instance sizes do not seem sized to be able to hold 2 shards on the same instance. I would really like to know if anyone has any ideas as to how and why opening/closing and index leads to spikes in disk usage. The ElasticSearch docs mention that closing an index can result in such a situation, but they don't give much other background.

Happy to provide any other info if helpful, thanks (so much) in advance!

Comment: Check the `prod` index settings to see how many replicas it is configured to have: `GET /prod/_settings`. What you can see in `elasticsearch.yml` is the default configuration, but each index can have its own configuration for primaries and replicas. Maybe, in your update analyzers command, you also changed the `number_of_replicas` value. That would explain why you have disk space issues now. Do you need 2 replicas? If not, change it to 1 and you should be ok: `curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/prod/_settings" -d'
{
  "index": {
    "number_of_replicas": 1
  }
}'`